# Image loading, JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx-11

im having a really weird prob here:
im building a music application here, so i ask the user to choose a file, and then i call the get metadata method, now here after generating the image for some reason the image does not display itself, and the weird part is after the user selects the same file again the image loads properly, basically onlly if the album cover exists in the folder initially it gets loaded
Why does this happen??
how can i fix it?

```
private void getMetadata(String path)
   {

       try {

           AudioFile f = AudioFileIO.read(new File(path));
           Tag tag = f.getTag();
           File directory = new File("/home/sazkikai/Music/Album_Cover");
           directory.mkdir();
           File album_cover = new File("/home/sazkikai/Music/Album_Cover/" + tag.getFirst(FieldKey.TITLE));

           Image Final_image = new Image("file:/home/sazkikai/Music/Album_Cover/" + tag.getFirst(FieldKey.TITLE));

           Title.setText(tag.getFirst(FieldKey.TITLE));
           Artist.setText(tag.getFirst(FieldKey.ARTIST));
           Album.setText(tag.getFirst(FieldKey.ALBUM));
           Gener.setText(tag.getFirst(FieldKey.GENRE));


           if (album_cover.exists()) {
               albumCoverView.setImage(Final_image);
           } else if (tag.getFirstArtwork() != null) {
               System.out.println("Fetching album cover..");
               byte[] raw_image = tag.getFirstArtwork().getBinaryData();
               //ByteArrayInputStream input = new ByteArrayInputStream(raw_image);
               BufferedImage songimage = ImageIO.read(new ByteArrayInputStream(raw_image));

               ImageIO.write(songimage, "jpg", new File("/home/sazkikai/Music/Album_Cover/" + tag.getFirst(FieldKey.TITLE)));
               System.out.println("setting album cover");
               albumCoverView.setImage(Final_image);
           }


       } catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}

   }
```

Comment: You are creating the image before it actually exists. How do you expect this to work?

Comment: wdym, if check if the cover exists, if it does then i directly set it, if it does not i check if the file has a album cover, if it does then i extract it into the folder and set it
i didnt get u, can you be a little more specific

Comment: But at that point in time you have constructed the image already with an URL pointing to a  non-existent file.

Comment: oh i get what ur saying, thx i fixed the prob, but why isnt it throwing a file not found exception??